# The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: mysql, debian, root

`mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx'; ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`

I have try like this:

```
mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'veisddq';
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded
```

OS: Debian 10
Mysql:8.0.33

I want to know how to set mysql root password

Comment: See [Chapter 11 Enabling Authentication :: Socket Peer-Credential Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/8.0/en/secure-deployment-configure-authentication.html): `Users authenticated by the auth_socket need not specify a password when connecting to the server, they can only connect from the local host through the Unix socket file.`. If you want to configure a password, you need to change the plugin and set the password at the same time, in the same command: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'veisddq';`.

Answer (score 0):

is root bu defaul, then you can run that command and set a new password

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).